# How to save display settings of your computer (windows10) to reapply on an other place

Tags: windows-10, display-settings

I'm working in an open space. Each desk is equipped with the same configuration : 2 screens connected by one docking station, that you connect with an usb-c cable to your laptop. The screens are not the same depending on the desk, but the docking station is the same everywhere.

**The problem :** When you change of desk the display settings reset so you have ton configure again.

I would like to write a script powershell which is able to save the display settings (json or csv) that the user wants, and an other one which is able to reapply the configuration saved when the user sits at an other desk. I tried many way to do it, successfully saved the configuration of the display settings (including screens position), but did'nt find a way to reapply the configuration.

Did someone have an idea?

Thank you

Comment: Which display settings are concerned?

Comment: Roaming Profiles died quite a long time ago. You may need to write a script that emulates roaming profiles.

Comment: We can only take stabs at this without knowing EXACTLY WHAT you are trying to reconfigure each time.